# Склонение фамилии Аника́я

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. *Юлия Аника́я* (ударение на последнюю "а").
Склоняется ли фамилия? Если да, то как (поясните по падежам: рус. яз. и бел. яз.)? И как во множественном числе будет?

Comment: А мужской вариант фамилии тоже Аникая или Аникой? Чаще всего подобные фамилии склоняются также как прилагательные морской, большой и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Ну про белорусский не буду (хотя, полагаю, там все так же). А вот по поводу русского...

Всё сложно. Без знания мужского варианта фамилии сказать наверняка ничего нельзя, да и зная его, можно говорить только о наиболее правдоподобном варианте.

При условии, что мужской вариант этой фамилии тоже Аникая, предпочел бы вариант склонения по типу существительного - как ***свая, Рая и Даная***: ***Аникая, Аникаи, Аникае, Аникаю, Аникаей, (об) Аникае.***
Множественного числа лучше избегать, хотя в принципе оно существует и нормировано.
***Аникаи, Аникай, Аникаям, Аникай, Аникаями, (об) Аникаях.***

Ну а если говорить вообще... Есть два типа склонения подобных образований - и одно редчайшее и не всеми признаваемое исключение.

Большинство славянких фамилий подобного типа (Машная, мужской вариант - Машной) не представляют сложностей при склонении (***Машная, Машной*** - и т.д.). Даже множественное число здесь не ограничивает легкость образования (***Машные, Машных, Машным...***)

Сложности возникают с другой группой фамилий (разного способа образования).
Фамилии на -**а**я, соотносимые с обоими полами носителей без изменения (в том числе - абхазского происхождения) склоняются по вышеприведенному образцу: **Цхакая, Цхакаи, Цхакае, Цхакаю, Цхакаей, (о) Цхакае.**
Сюда же следует отнести фамилии непонятного или неоднозначного происхождения. Пример - ***Киртбая***. Эта фамилия может иметь мужской вариант ***Киртбай*** (неизвестной мне этимологии, но подтверждаемый зарегистрированной формой "Киртбаев") или быть фонетическим вариантом абхазской фамилии ***Кирцбая***. Разбираться в деталях тут, как правило, невозможно, лучше просто принять указанный вариант склонения.
По правилам этот же тип склонения должен быть у фамилии **Гурцкая** (Гурцкая, Гурцкаи, Гурцкае...). Но носители языка уже настолько привыкли склонять по "русскому" варианту (Гурцкой) , что правильный вариант ими совершенно не воспринимается. Однако и "русский" вариант абсолютно невозможен даже по формальным причинам (мужскую-то фамилию Гурцкая так не просклоняешь). В качестве некоторого компромисса предлагается эту (и только эту!) фамилию не склонять вовсе.

Фамилия Аникая производит впечатление славянской (хотя и это может быть обманчиво), но за отсутствием достоверной информации о мужском её варианте (он просто не встречается даже при гугло-поиске) меньшим из зол, как уже сказал, полагаю склонять её по образцу существительного