# Склоняется ли фамилия Бородуля женского рода

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Как правильно писать в вопросе кому: Бородуля или Бородуле ?

Comment: У фамилии нет рода. Есть мужской и женский **варианты**.

Answer (score 1):

Склоняется. **Кому: Бородуле.**

> 13.1.12. Склоняемость-несклоняемость фамилий, пишущихся с буквой я на конце, зависит только от места ударения и происхождения фамилии.
>
> Несклоняемы фамилии французского происхождения с ударением на конце:
>   Золя, Труайя.
>
> Все прочие фамилии на я склоняемы; таковы Головня, Зозуля, Сырокомля,
>   Гамалея, Гойя, Шенгелая, Данелия, Берия.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482

От себя могу только добавить, что стаья по ссылке не догма, она постоянно пополняется различными уточнениями (вот пример: [Склонение фамилии Аника́я](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456363)). Но в отношении рассматриваемой фамилии **Бородуля** не похоже, что возможны исключения из общего правила. Фамилию рекомендуется склонять, даже если носитель против.

Answer (score 0):

Фамилия `Бородуля` и в мужском и в женском роде склоняются тривиально:

- Анна Бородуля и Петр Бородуля
- от Анны Бородули и Петра Бородули
- к Анне Бородуле и Петру Бородуле
- про Анну Бородулю и Петра Бородулю
- за Анной Бородулей и Петром Бородулей
- об Анне Бородуле и Петре Бородуле

Фамилия на -я могла бы не склоняться, например, если это иностранная фамилия:

- Эмилю Золя